# How to show events by category using fullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using fullCalendar 3.9.0 to list activities and events for a membership org. They categorize their events as Social, Workshop and Project
These events are displayed with the Month view.

FYI, I am using Adobe BC
Events are defined as an array e.g.
Pulled in as a list with these tags
{id:{tag_bookingid}, groupid: "Social Event",title: "{tag_name_nolink}", url: "{tag_url}", start: "{tag_bookingyear}-{tag_bookingmonthnumeric}-{tag_bookingday}", color:"#5f7bc0"},

Is there a way to customize the calendar to show only events of one category at a time and using tabs or buttons in the header to switch between categories?

Examples would be appreciated.

Comment: You can filter and create new array of events depending on category. So you will have 3 arrays of categories. And depending on your tab, you can destroy fullcalendar and re-initialize it with events of specific category.

Comment: I was looking at views as an option for displaying the category buttons, but views dont seem to allow having their own arrays unless I am wrong. Could you explain in more detail your idea please.

Comment: Rather than destroying and re-creating the calendar as Kenny suggests, you would probably be better making use of event Sources to separate the events into a source per category, and then adding and removing those. Or, using a custom "events" callback function which will do the filtering for you (client-side, I assume), and running "refetchEvents" whenever the user changes the category selection, or if you prefer to do the filtering on the server you can simply pass the category ID to the server when you fetch the events and have it return the restricted list. It's up to you.

Comment: If you choose one of these approaches and get stuck, post your code and we can help you. FWIW I think probably the 2nd or 3rd of those is likely to be the simplest.

Comment: look at fullaclenadar 'removeEventSource' and 'addEventSource'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that I use to toggle event data:
it also uses cookies to remember the selection between visits; you would use a different function on page load to check for the cookie and set the event lists there.

```
function toggleEventList(obj) {
    var group = $(obj).data('group');
    if ( $(obj).data('active') === 'yes' ) {
        $(obj).data('active', 'no');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', '/cal-data-group?group='+group);

        var elCookie = $.cookie('calendarEventList');
        if (elCookie) {
            elCookie = $.parseJSON(elCookie);
            var idx = elCookie.indexOf(group);
            if ( idx > -1 ) {
                elCookie.splice(idx, 1);
            }
        }
        $.cookie('calendarEventList', JSON.stringify(elCookie), {expires:7, path:'/'});
    } else {
        $(obj).data('active', 'yes');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
            'addEventSource',
            { url: '/cal-data-group?group='+group, color: 'gray', textColor: 'black' }

        );
        var elCookie = $.cookie('calendarEventList');
        if (elCookie) {
            elCookie = $.parseJSON(elCookie);
            var idx = elCookie.indexOf(group);
            if ( idx == -1 ) {
                elCookie.push(group);
            }
        } else {
            elCookie = [group];
        }
        $.cookie('calendarEventList', JSON.stringify(elCookie), {expires:7, path:'/'});
    }
    $(obj).parent().toggleClass('active');


}
```